# grunt an angular project then it errors as Cannot find Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, concatenation

Hi I have a problem :) I developed an angular project and it works fine in my `localhost` `apache`. I'm using `angular 1.4.3` for frontend things and `node.js` for backend things. Now I need to use Grunt to version it. 
I did many config (such as that maple thing disabled.`it changes all variables names such as a,b,c from indexCounter,PersonCounter,AgencyCounter and it causes some problems.`) But I get an error everytime I try to run. It is like [module] cannot found. My project works on my local machine If I dont grunt it but after the grunt I take 3 files as `vendor.js vendor2.js and app.js`. In `vendor.js` I have `native angular js` files. In `vendor2.js` I have `plugins`. and lastly In `app.js` I have `controllers`. I'm added them in my index HTML in this order;

vendor.js
vendor2.js
app.js

Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem: In angular you cannot minify your code without using either `.$inject` or array syntax.

**Solution**

For each controller, directive, service etc. that you add to your module, you will have to add en extra array of strings specifying the dependencies that should be injected into you service, controller etc.

**Example**

Using `$inject` property

```
function mainController(indexCounter,PersonCounter,AgencyCounter) {
    //Controller implementation
}
mainController.$inject=['indexCounter','PersonCounter','AgencyCounter'];

angular
    .module('mymodule')
    .controller('mainController', mainController);
```

Using array

```
var mainController;
function controller(indexCounter,PersonCounter,AgencyCounter) {
    //Controller implementation
}
mainController=['indexCounter','PersonCounter','AgencyCounter', controller];

angular
    .module('mymodule')
    .controller('mainController', mainController);
```

When you don't specify the dependecies in an array, angular will try to find an registered dependency based on its' parameter name. e.g. `function mainController(indexCounter) {}`, then angular will try to find a registered dependency called `indexCounter`. It works perfectly fine when the code is not minified. However, when minified the indexCounter parameter name will be changed to a shorter name, e.g. `a`. And when trying to find dependency `a` which is not registered in your app. It's gonna fail to instaciate your angular module.

Comment: Thank you so much but I already disabled that function of grunt. Now it is not change the names of the parameters. I believe there is something different. But your answer is great Thank you again.